# Promise issue with nested loops

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to write a server in node, and I am taking data from a SQL database, I have another function that does that, but inside this function I have that list of data (thisData).  In my server I need to query another server (offsite) to get a status update, update objects in the list based on this, and then respond with the JSON data.

I've been working on this for a long time and tried to find solutions based on other answers on here and I've yet to find something.  I was originally trying to do this with just callbacks, but now I'm trying to do it with Promise.all()

I have my object thisData, it is a list of three "areas" which each contain a list of objects.

Both of these code snippets are inside a standard listener function for the standard http lib:

```
var server = http.createServer((request, response => {...
```

Immediately inside this function I also have a call to get the data:

```
getData(function(Data){
    thisData = JSON.parse(data);
```

all the code snippets are inside this getData which is inside my listener function.

I also have a function that returns a promise to do the async web query:

```
var statusRequest = function(myArea, obj){
    var url = 'https://www.example.com/data/' + obj.id + '/mode.json';
    var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: url,
    strictSSL: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': config.auth_key,
        'Accept': "application/json",
        }
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, function (err, body, resp) {
            var status = JSON.parse(resp).mode;
            if (status == "success") thisData[area][obj.col].status = 0;
            else if (status == "fail") thisData[area][obj.col].status = 1;
            else thisData[area][obj.col].status = -1;
            resolve(thisData[area][obj.col].status);
        });
    });

}
```

Then I have a loop that traverses the areas and objects, and I add each promise to a list and call Promise.all(), then I respond with the updated list:

```
var promises = [];

Object.keys(thisData).forEach(function(area){
    for (var col = 0; col < thisData[area].length; col++){
        promises.push(statusRequest(area, thisData[area][col]));
    }
});
Promise.all(promises).then( (val) => {
    console.log(val);
    response.end(JSON.stringify(thisData));
});
```

I was initially having problems with all the promises resolving when col == thisData[area].length, and so I passed the actual object (which contains its own column information) into the statusRequest function so it shouldn't matter if the col variable changes.

The problem I'm having is that my console prints the correct status, but my JSON response does not contain the correct status, in fact it seems as though none of them are updating.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What web framework are you using? Express? Stdlib http?

Comment: This looks fine (maybe apart from the global `thisData` variable and your choice of arguments for the `statusRequest` method). Please show us how you are constructing `thisData`.

Comment: I updated the post, I am using the standard http library, all of my code snippets are inside a larger callback which is inside of my http listener function

Comment: hmm... Why is fail 1, and success 0? isn't that backwards?

Comment: I'm used to the unix convention of 0 meaning success and nonzero being fail, but in this case it doesn't matter because the client is written by me as well!

Comment: Hard to tell if this is the issue without seeing all of your code, but in the definition of `statusRequest` you're calling the first argument `myArea` but attempting to refer to it later with `area`. I don't know what `area` will be at this point, but it would probably mess up your array updates.

Comment: I think that was it, after trying this for such a long time with different ways of using promises, I figured it was just another problem with the method I was doing it, thanks for your help!

Comment: It so pains me to see people writing code that completely ignores errors.  You HAVE to process the `err` parameter coming back from `request()`.  If you want to use promises, then you should be using the `request-promise` library which already wraps `request()` in a promise layer for you and then you need to pay attention to both `.then()` and `.catch()` to handle all cases properly.